# What is a good starting point to read about Wolverine and the X-Men?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, x-men, wolverine, wolverine-and-the-x-men

Can someone direct me to which comic or series of comics to start reading so I can understand Logan's story line better?

Is there an order I should be reading the comics in?  Is the X-Men story over?

EDIT for ADDT'L info:

I would like to read some storyline, the best, for Wolverine. I would like to start (maybe read the prequel first if there is).

My 2nd question was, if the X-Men story has ended or is there still comics being published upto date.

Comment: hmm.. any one??

Comment: I'm confused as to whether you mean the current, ongoing "Wolverine and the X-Men" comic book, or just the characters of Wolverine and the X-Men in general. Also some information on what knowledge you have of the characters right now would be helpful (movies, 90s comics, cartoons, etc), just to figure out what to include in a recommendation.

Comment: edited for additonal info sir

Comment: @Sid Comics tend to have multiple continuities and reboots, so AFAIK there's several different "X-Men stories" out there

Comment: I see. so anybody can give me a good story, howbout a good Comics to read. a link to a logo.

Comment: “Is the X-Men story over?” Totally! All finished. Marvel felt it should invest some creativity into making new characters instead of endlessly milking the same ha ha ha ha ha ha sorry couldn’t keep a straight face through that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about sticking to the main Marvel continuity, you could pick up the Ultimate X-Men line.

It started as a reboot/reimagining of the Marvel Universe in the early 2000s, so you only have ~9 years of history instead of 50-60.

Of course, it rapidly got it's own convoluted continuity.  Ultimate X-Men ended a few years ago with the Ultimatum story arc, and the story picked up (along with the rest of the Ultimate lines) in Marvel Ultimate Comics: X-Men.

It's a VERY different world than the current modern continuity, though.

Comment: but would you consider this more interesting to read than the answer Mr Brett gave? I might be able to buy these because its in the 2000s.

Comment: @Sid It's interesting, all right.  I can't really say how it compares, but it certainly is easier to get into - you don't have to understand 40+ years of backstory, some of which is contradictory.  Pick up one or two of the trade paperbacks (in order, of course) and see if you like it.

Answer (score 8):

To get an overview of Wolverine, there are a number of storylines that can be read to give a nice overview of the character. Wolverine is a character that has been around since 1974, so he has a lot of history, both with and without the X-Men. I'd recommend:

- [Incredible Hulk #180-181 (1974)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785130659): Wolverine's debut appearance from 1974. It's his first appearance, so it's as good a place as any to start.
- [Giant-Size X-Men #1, X-Men #94-100 (1975-1976)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785137025): Wolverine joins the X-Men as part of their second generation (alongside Colossus, Storm, Nightcrawler, etc.). This collection covers his first adventures with the team.
- [X-Men #109, 120-121 (1978-1979)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785155139): Wolverine's origin is briefly explored for the first time, mostly covering his history with the Canadian superteam Alpha Flight.
- [Wolverine #1-4, Uncanny X-Men #172-173 (1982)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785137246): This is the first solo Wolverine story, covering his time in Japan and courtship of Mariko Yashida. The issues of Uncanny X-Men cover his attempted wedding with Mariko. All are pretty integral to his character, and this is widely considered to be the definitive Wolverine story.
- [Uncanny X-Men #205, Marvel Comics Presents #72-84 (1986, 1991)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785113703): Barry Windsor-Smith told some definitive Wolverine stories, including the epic Weapon X storyline that showed how Wolverine got his adamantium skeleton. This is also considered essential.
- [Wolverine: Origin #1-6 (2001-2002)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785137270): After nearly 30 years of existence, Marvel finally got around to telling Wolverine's definitive origin with this mini-series. This goes all the way back to Canada in the mid-1800s and starts with Wolverine as a child.
- [X-Men: Schism (2011)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785156682): If you want to jump into the current adventures of Wolverine and/or the X-Men, then this storyline is essential since it sets up the current status quo.
- [Wolverine & The X-Men #1-7 (2011-2012)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785156798): Wolverine currently runs a school for mutants in Westchester, alongside the X-Men, and this is where that storyline starts.

As for your second question, yes, Wolverine and X-Men comics are still being published today. Comic books as a medium tend to latch on to what is popular and publish them until they are not popular anymore...or even well past it. That's why characters like Superman, Batman, Spider-Man, the X-Men and Wolverine have been continuously published for the past 40-70 years. Just this month alone, March 2012, Marvel is publishing 16 comics starring either Wolverine or the X-Men

- Avengers vs. X-Men
- Ultimate Comics X-Men
- Astonishing X-Men
- Uncanny X-Men
- Wolverine and the X-Men: Alpha & Omega
- Wolverine and the X-Men
- Wolverine
- Uncanny X-Force
- X-Men
- X-Men Legacy
- Daken: Dark Wolverine
- X-23
- New Mutants
- X-Factor
- X-Club
- Generation Hope

So there's a lot to choose from, and if you go into a local comic book shop, you'll see Wolverine on the covers of a bunch of comics. I'd recommend starting with any of the ones I've linked to.

Comment: thanks. Too bad this comic store in our mall near us doesnt have some of your list. I was going to collect after reading and give it as a gift maybe to my son if ill have one lol, when they get older. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should pick up the essential x-men trades (they are only about 15 buck and in black and white) and start with the chris claremont years. You'll get a good sense of where wolverine and the x-men came from and what the foundations are of the current iterrations.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up the trade reprints of Uncanny X-men is the most lucrative route and the best place to start reading, too. The entire Ultimate line at Marvel is overblown tripe, imo, and changes things that shouldn't have been; the movies, for the most part, are pulled from that line, sadly...The Avengers written as SHIELD agents and Nick Fury being black are just the tip of the iceberg; they changed everything about the X-men in that line.

The Claremont/Byrne run at the beginning of Uncanny X-men holds some of the best X-tales ever written, to this day.