# If you want to read and understand storylines like "House of M" and "A vs. X" do you need to be an X Men fan for the most part?

Tags: marvel, avengers, suggested-order

I am a little newer to comics and i'm going to start from Disassembled up. I think I am going to like the Avengers more than the X Men (not because of the movies but because the characters have a wide variety of backgrounds imo). So... if I do not want to read X books, but I am following Disassembled and up (because of the Avengers), should I skip HoM and A vs. X?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE! This question might be related to yours : [What is a good starting point to read about Wolverine and the X-Men?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13431/13418)

Answer (score 3):

Comic books are designed so that one can jump in at any time and read on with no prior experience of the characters. You might have trouble if you jumped into a storyline in progress, but if you start at the beginning of a new story arc you should be fine. It's a pity *Marvel* no longer has the opening flap with a little character history, as they did in the late-'90s, but even without that you shouldn't need to read earlier storylines to understand one in progress.

Crossover events happen fairly often in comic books, and can be slightly frustrating for someone who only reads one of the titles involved in the crossover. I remember many years ago, as a *Spider-Man* reader, being confronted by a *Spider-Man-Gen-X* crossover and not having a clue who anyone on the *Gen-X* side was except Jubilee, as I did not read the *Gen-X* books. If you're really having trouble, you can always simple *Wiki* the HoM and A vs X storylines to find out the key details.

Comment: "Comic books are designed so that one can jump in at any time and read on with no prior experience of the characters." Damn straight. The Chris Claremont Wolverine trade paperback that the recent movie was based on is a slightly odd read, because at the start of each issue Wolverine reminds the reader that he is a mutant with a healing factor, adamantium-laced skeleton and claws. We know, Wolverine!